# layout in html and css

Tags: html, css

when i apply following code,top left div and top right div overlap my text. i feel desire for shifting my text in the manner so that overlapping problem can be resolved.  can any one tell me the solution? i trying to use clear property to resolve this problem but this will not help me.. if there is some better and easy solution regarding to it you are requested to tell me because i am in new in the field of html and css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>
        layout
    </title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .topright{
            border:dashed 2px red;
            background-color:gray;
            margin:10px;
            padding:10px;
            position:absolute;
            left:0px;
            top:0px;
            clear:left;
        }
        .topleft{
            border:dashed 2px red;
            background-color:gray;
            margin:10px;
            padding:10px;
            position:absolute;
            right:0px;
            top:0px;
        }
        .bottomright{
            border:dashed 2px red;
            background-color:gray;
            margin:10px;
            padding:10px;
            position:absolute;
            left:0px;
            bottom:0px;
        }
        .bottomleft{
            border:dashed 2px red;
            background-color:gray;
            margin:10px;
            padding:10px;
            position:absolute;
            right:0px;
            bottom:0px;
        }
        .clearing{
            clear:right;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="topright">
        topright
    </div>
    <div class="topleft">
        topleft
    </div>
    <div class="bottomright">
        bottomright
    </div>
    <div class="bottomleft">
        bottomleft
    </div>
    <p class="clearing">
        The absence of romance in my history will, I fear, detract somewhat
        from its interest; but if it be judged useful by those inquirers who
        desire an exact knowledge of the past as an aid to the interpretation
        of the future, which in the course of human things must resemble if
        it does not reflect it, I shall be content.
    </p>
    <p>
        The absence of romance in my history will, I fear, detract somewhat
        from its interest; but if it be judged useful by those inquirers who
        desire an exact knowledge of the past as an aid to the interpretation
        of the future, which in the course of human things must resemble if
        it does not reflect it, I shall be content. In fine, I have written
        my work, not as an essay which is to win the applause of the moment,
        but as a possession for all time.
    </p>
    <p>
        The absence of romance in my history will, I fear, detract somewhat
        from its interest; but if it be judged useful by those inquirers who
        desire an exact knowledge of the past as an aid to the interpretation
        of the future, which in the course of human things must resemble if
        it does not reflect it, I shall be content. In fine, I have written
        my work, not as an essay which is to win the applause of the moment,
        but as a possession for all time.
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What is in those divs and why are they positioned like that?

Comment: A solution to do what ?

Comment: i am just learning layout with the help of css and html when i apply this code my top left div overlaps the text on the web page i am just want to shift my text so that overlapping problem can be solve

Comment: It would be better to use floats instead.

Comment: @Xareyo Are you sure, it is?

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use floats to keep the document flow:

HTML

```
<div class="topright">topright</div>
<div class="topleft">topleft</div>
<p class="clearing">
    The absence of romance in my history will, I fear, detract somewhat
    from its interest; but if it be judged useful by those inquirers who
    desire an exact knowledge of the past as an aid to the interpretation
    of the future, which in the course of human things must resemble if
    it does not reflect it, I shall be content.
</p>
<!-- ...rest of markup... -->
```

CSS

```css
.topright {
    border:dashed 2px red;
    background-color:gray;
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
    float: left;
}
.topleft {
    border:dashed 2px red;
    background-color:gray;
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
    float: right;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xareyo/k8rk5/1/)

Comment: No need for the inline declaration... otherwise good solution. +1

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q5wj7/)

**CSS**

```
.topright{
    border:dashed 2px red;
    background-color:gray;
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
    float: right;
}
.topleft{
    border:dashed 2px red;
    background-color:gray;
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
    float: left;
}
.bottomright{
    border:dashed 2px red;
    background-color:gray;
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
}
.bottomleft{
    border:dashed 2px red;
    background-color:gray;
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
}
.clearing{
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: i am just learning layout with the help of css and html when i apply this code my top left div overlaps the text on the web page i am just want to shift my text so that overlapping problem can be solve

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioning always takes the elements out of the normal Document flow. They are treated by the other elements as if they were not there (nowadays one would call that mobbing=D). You have to manually take care, that no overlapping takes place.

There are several solutions:

1. Float the elements to the left and right. This will then also be fixable with the `clear` statement you put on your paragraph.
2. Use absolute positioning, but apply margins to your paragraph to prevent the overlapping.

Demo of the second solution: http://jsfiddle.net/UK9u6/

In general, you should avoid using floats and absolute positionings if possible to prevent these kind of problems. Nowadays we have modern stuff like [flexbox layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) or [grid layouts](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/) (which sadly has [poor browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=grid) atm, but I'm sure this will catch up soon) which aim to accommodate the shortcomings of floats and absolute positions.

You definitely should have a look at these specifications (and the many demos which are available), as they are the certainly the future of web development regarding layout.

Comment: You are welcome! Here is an important link for each web developer: http://caniuse.com/ (I also included this in my answer).